# Opera post(GET)s the hash fragment of the URL

Tags: javascript, apache, opera

According to this line from Apache access log, it seems like Opera sometimes includes the hash fragment in the URI sent to server:

> [26/Apr/2011:01:09:03 +0200] "GET /dagbok/#type=food HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; nb) Presto/2.8.131 Version/11.10"

Any experience or insights on why it's doing that?

The URI should be trapped by jQuery's hash change event which in turn triggers .load() on the URI `/dagbok/food/`.

PS! The `500 Internal Server` occurs because the routing doesn't understand URIs with a hash-fragment in it. Neither should it.

**Update with RewriteRules:**

> RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteRule !.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php

Index.php then starts Zends front controller/router which is unable to find any route for this URI. Which is correct since this URI never should reach the server.

Comment: What version of Opera are you seeing this in?

Comment: Can you post some details about the server, the log looks strange as the server should ignore the fragment. Do you use some rewrite_rules?

Comment: @Roatin Marth As the log says it's Opera 11.10. Also saw it with 11.01, but noone uses that anymore.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Running with a basic `RewriteRule` which sends "everything" to index.php where Zends front controller/router parses the request URI. There it fails hard since it does not find a route for this URI. Added the `RewriteRule` to the original question.

Comment: Look at these links, is there any differences between them?

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791569/opera-postgets-the-hash-fragment-of-the-url%23tab-top

  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791569/opera-postgets-the-hash-fragment-of-the-url#tab-top

The url shown at status bar is same, but the first one includes %23 instead of '#'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess jQuery doesn't remove the #hash part from the URL before sending an XMLHttpRequest, and relies on the browser doing so. A quick test shows Opera doesn't. (This should probably be considered a bug in Opera - I don't think there is any standard covering this exact point but it's not doing what most others probably do.)

Comment: [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) actually describe how the fragment should behave in point `3.5. Fragment` stating: _As such, the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific processing of a URI; instead, the **fragment identifier is separated from the rest of the URI prior** to a dereference, and thus the identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced **solely by the user agent**, regardless of the URI scheme._

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Yes, and I can confirm it's a known bug that will likely be resolved in Opera's next version update. (The fix may not go in if there is a very minor release, i.e. 11.11 for a security issue or something, but it is in the pipeline.)